# Drush pm-update strange behavior

Tags: drush

I have a bunch of sites running both on Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 on my server. Every site has its own folder (ie. I don't use multisites feature). I created a small script to run `drush pm-update` on every site.

All of this is working okay, but I noticed something strange. Often when I run, either manually or via the script above mentioned, the `drush pm-update` finds a update for a version of a module or core in one site, but not for others.

I tried to clear drush cache but it showed no result.

Have anyone seen this behavior and has a hint of what it is? I'm curious about it :-)

**Update**: Now I think it's related to this issue https://drupal.org/node/952394

Comment: Please don't post answers inside questions. You will be able to post an answer properly pretty soon. It's only a time limit, so please be patient :) Or if you prefer, I may post your answer as a community wiki right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, every Drupal site has a variable, in `{variable}` table, called `update_last_check` that stores the last time the site had a update check. This variable is mostly update by Drupal cron. It happens that, in some of my sites, this date is too small to need a new check, so Drush skipped it and considered the site up to date. So, in other words, if you want to ensure there's a new update, you should first run a `drush cron` and then run a `drush pm-update`.

Comment: OP's answer, posted by me as CW at his request.